# How to solve pagination-Error in cakePHP with cakeDC searchplugin

Tags: cakephp, search, plugins, cakephp-2.3, cakedc

i'm using the searchplugin from cakeDC (https://github.com/CakeDC/search) with cakePHP 2.3.0. That Plugin works fine. I had a little error in the index-action like this. Thanks for that.

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property AtlasController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\AtlasController.php, line 47]
```

My Index-action

```
public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->Atla->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    $this->Atla->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('atlas', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('_serialize',array('atlas'));
}
```

The question is, how can i solve it? So i found out a way thats so simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution, that runs on my implementation.

I change the paginate()-call from.

```
$this->set('atlas', $this->paginate());
```

to the new paginate()-call.

```
this->set('atlas', $this->paginate($this->Atla->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs)));
```

Here the new index-action.

```
public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->Atla->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('atlas', $this->paginate($this->Atla->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs)));
    $this->set('_serialize',array('atlas'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why the code did not work out of the box is the `['options']` key. Remove the key from `$this->paginate['options']` and add the model as an argument for paginate in 
`$this->set()` and the pagination should work as expected. See the modified code example below.

```
public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = $this->Atla->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    $this->Atla->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('atlas', $this->paginate('Atla'));
    $this->set('_serialize',array('atlas'));
}
```